# Duda acerca de type coertion en objetos

Tags: javascript

Estaba leyendo sobre el `type coertion` y qué tipo de conversión disparan los operadores cuando los operandos son incompatibles con él.

Llegué a esta parte del tutorial en la que se decía esto:

> Objects are converted to primitives via the internal [[ToPrimitive]]
>   method, which is responsible for both numeric and string conversión.

¿Ese método `ToPrimitive`, a dónde esta declarado?, ¿por qué se le dice método interno?

> [[ToPrimitive]] is passed with an input value and preferred type of
>   conversion: Number or String. preferredType is optional

¿A qué se refiere con que `ToPrimitive` es pasado con un valor de  entrada y un tipo preferido de conversión? ¿Cuál es ese valor de entrada? ¿En qué momento de donde se obtienen esos valores de entradas llamados tipo preferido y valor de entrada?

Con valor de entrada creo que se refiere a los valores en si que se van a convertir, osea los operandos del operador

¿Quién invoca a este método?

Luego se tiene esto:

> Both numeric and string conversion make use of two methods of the
>   input object: valueOf and toString . Both methods are declared on
>   Object.prototype and thus available for any derived types, such as
>   Date, Array, etc.

Luego...

> Numeric conversion first calls valueOf (3) with a fallback to toString
>   (2). String conversion does the opposite: toString (2) followed by
>   valueOf (3).

Hay alguna forma de predecir si por ejemplo en la conversión numérica se recurrirá a `toString()` en vez de `valueOf()` según el objeto que se quiere convertir?

Según lo que he entendido cuando el operador requiere de una conversión numérica primero llama a `valueOf()` y si no puede convertir el tipo llama a `toString()`

Si no puede con ninguno de los dos métodos lanza `type error`

¿Hay alguna forma en que se sepa cuando se lanzara `type error`?

> Most built-in types do not have valueOf, or have valueOf returning
>   this object itself, so it’s ignored because it’s not a primitive.
>   That’s why numeric and string conversion might work the same — both
>   end up calling toString().

¿Con esto se refiere a aquellos objetos que construimos con una función constructora en vez de hacerlo de forma literal ya que en objetos creados así no hay prototipo padre?

> Different operators can trigger either numeric or string conversion
>   with a help of preferredType parameter. But there are two exceptions:
>   loose equality == and binary + operators trigger default conversion
>   modes (preferredType is not specified, or equals to default). In this
>   case, most built-in types assume numeric conversion as a default,
>   except Date that does string conversion.

¿Los operadores como tal no son los que definen si la conversión sera numérica o de cualquier otro tipo? No logro entender que es el `preferredType` tan poco comprendo muy bien en que "El operador `==` y el `+` dispararan la conversión por defecto si el preferredType no es especificado o es igual al predeterminado.

Las citas son provenientes de este tutorial:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839/

Comment: Posible duplicado: [Conversion de tipos en javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/294763/65)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Ese método ToPrimitive, a donde esta declarado?, ¿porque se le dice método interno?

`ToPrimite` hace referencia a un proceso interno del compilador de `JS`, algo que hace el lenguaje automáticamente al realizar una operación.

> ¿A que se refiere con que ToPrimitive es pasado con un valor de entrada y un tipo preferido de conversión? ¿Cual es ese valor de entrada? ¿En que momento de donde se obtienen esos valores de entradas llamados tipo preferido y valor de entrada?

Por ejemplo, cuando se intenta realizar una comparación entre dos variables de distinto tipo, supongamos:

```js
var a = {};
var b = 1
// Si realizamos la comparación 
var c = a == b;
console.log(a.valueOf(), b, c)
```

Entonces para poder asignar un calor a `c`, es cuando se invoca a `ToPrimitive` sobre ambas variables.

Este analiza `a` (*valor de entrada*) al detectar que es un `object` invocara a `valueOf()` o `toString()` para obtener valor primitivo (*ver ref 1*). Luego hará lo mismo con `b`.

Una vez obtenido el valor primitivo de ambas, procederá a realizar la comparación.

> Hay alguna forma de predecir si por ejemplo en la conversión numérica se recurrirá a toString() en ves de valueOf() según el objeto que se quiere convertir?

Todos los objetos NO primitivos extienden (*por prototipo*) de `object`.
Todos los `object` poseen [ambos métodos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object#Methods).

- `.valueOf()` dependiente del tipo  de objeto devuelve el valor primitivo (`eg: new Bool, new Number`) o un referencia al objeto mismo (`this`).
- `.toString()` devuelve una cadena con el nombre del tipo de objeto (`[object type]`).

Quiere decir que si pisamos `.valueOf()` y devolvemos un primitivo, entonces nunca se llamará a `.toString()`.

```js
var a = {
  toString: () => 1
};
var b = 1;
console.log(a.valueOf(), b, a == b); // No usa valueOf ya que devuelve un NO primitivo

var c = {
  toString: () => 1,
  valueOf: () => 0,
};
console.log(c.valueOf(), b, c == b); // Usa  valueOf ya que devuelve un primitivo
```

> ¿Hay alguna forma en que se sepa cuando se lanzara type error?

Un [`TypeError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/TypeError) se produce cuando un operando o argumento que se pasa a una función es incompatible con el tipo esperado por el operador o la función.

```js
var a = null
try {  a.hola(); } // Operacion inválida
catch (e) { console.log(e.name, e.message); }
```

> ¿Con esto se refiere a aquellos objetos que construimos con una función constructora en vez de hacerlo de forma literal ya que en objetos creados así no hay prototipo padre?

No, se refiere a que, normalmente los distintos tipos de objetos no tiene un `valueOf` 
 o retornan un no primitivo, y es por esto que siempre se termine llamando a `toString`.

> ¿Los operadores como tal no son los que definen si la conversión sera numérica o de cualquier otro tipo?

No, `preferredType` es el parámetro que se le indica (*internamente*) al llamar a `ToPrimitive` (`eg: ToPrimitive(input, preferredType)`).

Este parámetro es "omitido" cuando se usan los operadores `==` o `+`.
Pero cuando se usan operadores como `===`, `-`, etc. internamente es establecido para intentar obtener un resultado "válido"

```js
var a = 1;
var b = '2';
var c = a - b; //preferedType number
console.log(c, typeof c === 'number');

var a = 1;
var b = '2';
var c = a + b; //preferedType default (depende del tipo de todas las vars involucradas)
console.log(c, typeof c === 'number');
```

---

### Update

> ¿Hay algún modo de saber si el preferredType sera number o string, cuando este es establecido?

Puedes usar [`Symbol.toPrimitive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive) que es un símbolo que especifica una propiedad (*usado con valor de función*) que se llama para convertir un objeto en un valor primitivo correspondiente.

La función se llama con argumento `hint` tipo cadena, que especifica el `preferred type` del valor primitivo del resultado.

```js
var obj1 = {};
console.log(+obj1);     // NaN
console.log(`${obj1}`); // "[object Object]"
console.log(obj1 + ''); // "[object Object]"

var obj2 = {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    if (hint == 'number') {
      return 10;
    }
    if (hint == 'string') {
      return 'hello';
    }
    return true;
  }
};
console.log(+obj2);     // 10        -- hint is "number"
console.log(`${obj2}`); // "hello"   -- hint is "string"
console.log(obj2 + ''); // "true"    -- hint is "default"
```

---

Referencias:

1. [Tipos de datos y estructuras en JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Tipos_de_datos)
2. [Object en Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object)
3. [Comparadores de igualdad e identidad
   en Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)
4. [Type coercion in JavaScript](https://2ality.com/2019/10/type-coercion.html)

Comment: ¿Hay algún modo de saber si el preferredType sera number o string, cuando este es establecido?. olvide poner esto en mi pregunta, lo siento.

Comment: @EngelSandoval, en [esta publicacíón](https://2ality.com/2019/10/type-coercion.html) mas info sobre este tema