# Conversion de tipos en javascript

Tags: javascript, conversión-de-tipos, tipos

## Nota:

> La pregunta es amplia, pero por su valor como documentación y como respuesta canónica a muchas preguntas similares, considero que debería dejarse abierta.

Me es frecuente encontrarme en javascript haciendo alguna funcion y convirtiendo varias veces entre tipos de datos para poder usar algun metodo(`split()`, `join()`, `map()`) pues algunos funcionan para `Strings`, otros para `Array`, etc. y *no son tantos los tipos de datos como la cantidad de formas  que hay para convertir entre tipos* en este lenguaje, unas mas sencillas que otras, algunas mas rapidas... pero me gustaria una especie de guia para convertir entre los diferentes tipos y de ser posible las mas eficientes:
**Si es muy amplia la pregunta estos son los que mas me interesan:**

**Conversiones:**

1. `Number` a `String`
2. `String` a `Number`
3. Como se convierte a tipos especificos `Integer`, `Float`, `Double` *esto me causa dudas en javascript*.
4. `Boolean` a `String`
5. `String` a `Boolean`
6. `char` a `String`
7. `String` a `char`

Comment: En este enlace puedes encontrar información detallada de todos los tipos de conversión en javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp

Comment: La pregunta es muy amplia y tiene muchas soluciones posibles, el concepto clave en la práctica es coerción, aquí te dejo un enlace https://www.google.com/amp/s/jherax.wordpress.com/2014/07/05/javascript-coercion/amp/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como han dicho Emeeus y the-breaker, existen muchas pero muchas formas de convertir un valor a otro en javascript, pero ten en cuenta que convertir a tipos especificos en javascript, no funciona como en otros lenguajes de programacion como por ejemplo **java**, aca en **javascript**, solo tenemos tres palabras magicas para definir variables, teniendo en cuenta esto, tenemos las siguientes formas de convertir datos:

1.)  **Number** to **String**

```
numero.toString();    //Cualquier numero flotante o no flotante tiene este metodo para convertir a cadena de texto.
```

mas información acerca de toString:  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp

2.)  **String** to **Number**

```
parseFloat(str);
parseInt(str);
```

A las funciones parseFloat y parseInt que se pueden referenciar de manera global porque son propiedad del objeto superglobal window, podemos pasarle una cadena de texto (string) y nos retornaran el numero correspondiente según la función usada.

para mas información acerca de parseFloat y parseInt:

[parseFloat](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp)
[parseInt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

3.) **Integer**, **Float** y **Double**

las clases **Integer**, **Float**, **Double**, no son tipos, son clases, algo diferente seria int, float, double, (estos si son tipos), esto en otros lenguajes, ya que por ejemplo en javascript la clase  **Float** no existe, **Double** mucho menos e **Integer** tampoco existen en javascript, como se convierten entonces numeros con tipos int, float y double?, respuesta:

> En javascript no es necesario convertir a tipos de datos numericos
>   especificos si el tipo de dato original es un dato de tipo numerico
>   (Number), esto debido a que para javascript, los tipos int, float y
>   double son lo mismo, un numero, esto significa que por ese lado nunca
>   tendrás un error de tipos, **OJO** esto aplica solo si el dato
>   original es un numero.

En caso de que el dato original sea una cadena de texto, puedes usar según lo que requieras, las funciones parseFloat o parseInt vistas anteriormente, parseInt es el equivalente a que te devuelva un dato de tipo int o Integer, y parseFloat es el equivalente a que te devuelva **SIEMPRE** un dato de tipo double, (javascript toma cualquier valor flotante con un tamaño equivalente al de un double), asi el numero no sea muy grande, y como javascript no distingue entre tipos de numeros especificos, para javascript ese 'double', puede ser tratado tambien como un 'float' tranquilamente.

4.) **Boolean** to **String**

Esto es muy sencillo, simplemente usa el metodo **toString**:

```
let miBooleano = true;
booleano.toString();   //Output: 'true'
```

5.) **String** to **Boolean**:

para convertir de string a boolean, (cosa que normalmente no es estrictamente necesaria en muchos casos en javascript), javascript no provee una solución, función o metodo directo, por lo que una forma de hacerlo es mediante un operador ternario:

```js
function toStrictBoolean(str){
   return str == "true" ? true : false;
}

console.log(typeof(toStrictBoolean('true')));
```

6.) **char** a **string** y viceversa

Javascript no distingue entre **char** y **string**, para javascript un solo caracter:

```
let char = 'A';
```

Es lo mismo que una cadena de texto (string):

```
let string = 'ABCDEFGH lo que sea etc...';
```

como resultado en javascript no existe conversion de **string** a **char** o de **char** a **string**, de hecho en javascript nisiquiera existe el tipo char, el char es mas bien representado como tipo string, por lo que no te preocupes por esta conversion.

**Extras**

Hay otra forma de convertir para el caso de **string** a **int**, ojo, solo para convertir de string a int, no funciona viceversa y tampoco devuelve flotantes (siempre devuelve enteros), y es por medio de el operador binario | :

```
let miVariable = "7.42";
```

miVariable es un string que contiene el 7.42, ahora probemos una conversion rapida:

```
miVariable = miVariable | 0;    //El resultado es que ahora es un tipo entero y guarda el valor 7.
```

aparte esta misma forma se puede usar en vez de usar la función parseInt para convertir numeros flotantes a enteros rapidamente:

```js
let pi = 3.1416;
    pi = pi | 0;

console.log(pi);
```

Como ultimo dato, espero no te estuvieras refiriendo a **Java** cuando hiciste la pregunta, ya que **Java** y **Javascript** son lenguajes de programación muy diferentes, si estas preguntas eran realmente dirigidas a java, esta respuesta no es acorde entonces con lo que realmente quisiste preguntar.

Comment: +1 por el truco de convertir de `string` a `int`

Comment: Muchas Gracias! @Riven... si me referia a Javascript que eh tenido que estar buscando por separado cada conversion de tipo que son muchas, muchos trucos y mañas... para java se encuentra mas informacion

Answer (score 6):

La respuesta de Riven cubre prácticamente todo, pero voy a añadir un par de trucos o detalles:

#### Conversión de String a numérico:

El operador +, usado sobre un valor, transforma ese valor a numérico. Su comportamiento no es igual que parseFloat, pero en muchos casos se puede intercambiar:

```js
let textos = ['35.81','2','2.56hola'];

textos.forEach(texto => {
  let num= +texto;
  console.log('Usando el operador +:',typeof num, num);
  
  num= parseFloat(texto);
  console.log('Usando parseFloat:',typeof num, num);
});
```

Como puedes ver, el operador `+` obliga a que **toda la cadena** sea transformable en número o dará un NaN (Not a Number), mientras que `parseFloat` simplemente transforma la parte que se pueda y cuando se encuentre un caracter extraño, simplemente para y transforma lo anterior.

Otra forma de transformar a numérico es usar `Number`, que tiene el mismo comportamiento que **`+`**

#### Conversión de cualquier tipo primitivo a String:

El constructor de la clase String, si lo usamos sin la palabra reservada **`new`**, transforma el parámetro recibido a String:

```js
let numero= 9.5;
let obj = { a: 1,b:'texto'};
let array =[0,1,2,'hola'];
let booleano=false;

let string1=String(9);
console.log(typeof string1, string1);
console.log(String(booleano));
//No es útil con objetos, es mejor usar JSON.stringify:
let string2=String(obj); 
console.log(typeof string2, string2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

//La excepción son los arrays, con los que funciona bastante bien
let string3=String(array); 
console.log(typeof string3, string3);
```

#### Conversión de numérico a String con formato local:

Un último detalle: En inglés se usa el punto para separar los decimales y (opcionalmente) la coma para separar miles o millones. Es lo contrario que en español, francés o prácticamente cualquier otro idioma europeo. Por tanto puedes tener problemas a la hora de querer mostrar valores a un usuario español.

La solución es usar toLocaleString():

```js
let numero= 1999000.5;

console.log(numero)
console.log(numero.toLocaleString('es'))
console.log(numero.toLocaleString('es',{useGrouping: false}))

console.log(numero.toLocaleString('es',{
  useGrouping: true,
  currency: 'EUR',
  style: 'currency'
}))
```

Las combinaciones de opciones son grandes, puedes mirar la [documentación aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: vaya... ya sabia que existia la función toLocaleString pero nunca me habia dado por verla, asi que para eso sirve... y yo que hice una función en una respuesta especificamente para eso... que terrible jajajaja... :c