# Cuales son las diferencias entre parseFloat y Number al convertir numeros?

Tags: javascript, entrada, conversión-de-tipos

Tanto `Number()` como `parseFloat()` tienen resultados iguales al convertir numeros de texto a un numero (tipo `number`). Pero hay otros casos los resultados son muy diferentes.

```js
// Casos normales

    console.log(Number('123.45')); // 123.45
    console.log(parseFloat('123.45')); // 123.45

//En algunos casos sus resultados son distintos:

    console.log(Number('1aaa')); // NaN
    console.log(parseFloat('1aaa')); // 1

    console.log(Number('0x20')); // 32
    console.log(parseFloat('0x20')); // 0
```

Esta claro que no son funciones equivalentes, asi que cual es la diferencia de implementacion entre ambas y cual sería mas recomendable a la hora de convertir numeros desde una entrada de usuario (texto)?

Igualmente, si hubiera otra manera mas recomendable, cual sería?

Comment: Esta pregunta ya tiene respuesta en otra más amplia: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/294763/conversion-de-tipos-en-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

Según la [documentación de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseFloat):

> parseFloat convierte su argumento, una cadena, y devuelve un número de punto flotante. Si encuentra un carácter diferente al signo (+ o -), numerales (0-9), un punto decimal o un exponente, devuelve el valor hasta ese punto e ignora ese carácter y todos los correctos siguientes. Se permiten espacios anteriores y posteriores.

Es decir va a convertir los números que encuentre al principio de la cadena, si se topa con un caracter no numérico va a devolver solo los números que encontró al principio de la cadena ya convertidos.

```js
console.log(parseFloat("3.14PI"));
```

Por otro lado, [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number):

> Si el argumento no puede ser convertido a un número, devuelve NaN.

Esto quiere decir que si se encuentra con algo que no es número, automáticamente devuelve `NaN`.

```js
console.log(Number("3.14PI"));
```

Otras diferencias:

- `parseFloat()` es una función implementada, mientras `Number()` es el constructor de un objeto **primitivo.**
- `parseFloat()` es capaz de convertir literales números en base 10, mientras que `Number()` es capaz de convertir cualquier litera que sea considerado numérico.