# ¿Cómo determinar un número mayor en JS?

Tags: javascript

El problema es que si ingreso 500 y 8 el programa me dice que 8 es mayor *¿Por qué pasa esto y cómo lo soluciono?*

```
var num1=prompt("Ingresa el primer numero: ");
var num2=prompt("Ingresa el segundo numero: ");


if(num1>num2){
    alert(num1+" Es el mayor.")
}else{
    alert(num2+" Es el mayor.")
}
```

Comment: Los está evaluando como strings por eso, debes leerlos como número así `Number(num1)` y lo mismo para la otra variable

Comment: Prueba con parseint if(parseint(num1)>parseint(num2))) o num1=parseint(prompt...

Comment: El unicode 8 es mayor que 5.

Comment: @Gabitohh una respuesta donde dejaras alguna fuente de consulta del mismo sería genial para que de manera más amplia se entienda el por qué del fallo no crees track3r ?

Answer (score 5):

### ¿Por qué pasa esto?

Los strings se comparan caracter por caracter, con su valor respectivo valor en el estándar de [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters). Esto quiere decir que se va a comparar la primer letra de cada operando y la siguiente en caso de que las anteriores sean iguales.

Los números en Unicode se ubican de desde la posición [48](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0) a la [57](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9). Entonces, cuando se comparan valores como strings, se evalúa el código de su primer caracter y **no el valor que representan numéricamente**

```js
let a = "10";
let b = "9";
let mayor = a > b ? a : b;

console.log(mayor);
```

A pesar de 10 ser mayor que 9, 9 es mayor. Al ser variables de tipo string se comparan los valores Unicode de sus dígitos, 9 vale 57 y 1 vale 49. Es decir realmente la comparación que se evalúa en `mayor` es `49 > 57`.

Los literales de strings que son números **no representan lo mismo** que los números de verdad.

### ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Es cuestión de evaluar, los strings que recibe `prompt()` como números.

```js
var num1 = prompt("Ingresa el primer numero: ");
var num2 = prompt("Ingresa el segundo numero: ");


if (parseFloat(num1) > parseFloat(num2)) {
    alert(num1 + " Es el mayor.")
} else {
    alert(num2 + " Es el mayor.")
}
```

Este ejemplo usa [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseFloat), pero existen [otras maneras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/294763/conversion-de-tipos-en-javascript), cualquiera sirve.

Comment: Excelente respuesta +1, ya que sabía cómo corregirlo pero no en detalle el por qué, así que gracias

Answer (score 1):

Esto sucede porque el resultado del prompt es un string y si comparas 500 con 8, 8 es mayor que 5, para considerarlo como número tienes que convertirlo de la siguiente manera.

```js
var num1 = prompt("Ingresa el primer numero: ");
var num2 = prompt("Ingresa el segundo numero: ");


if (Number(num1) > Number(num2)){
    alert(num1 + " Es el mayor.")
} else {
    alert(num2 + " Es el mayor.")
}
```

También puedes considerar usar `parseInt()` o `parseFloat()` dependiendo de tus necesidades.

Answer (score 1):

Así es:

```js
var num1= Number(prompt("Ingresa el primer numero: "));
var num2= Number(prompt("Ingresa el segundo numero: "));


if(num1>num2){
    alert(num1 + " Es el mayor.")
}else if(num2 > num1){
    alert(num2 +" Es el mayor.")
} else{
alert("Son iguales")
}
```

Lo que pasó es que al guardar los valores los toma como Strings, lo unico que hay que hacer es aclararle al computador que los valores son de tipo numérico. Esto lo hice con el `Number()` aunque tambien se puede hacer con el `parseInt()` (si es un número entero) o el `parseFloat` si es decimal.

Recomiendo que leas esto:

[Tipos de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias mi hermano, ya pude resolver.....

Comment: Acuerdate de marcar mi respuesta con un tick para que la gente vea que esta respuesta fue la que te sirvio