# como sumar objetos en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando una clase Vector2:

```js
class Vector2 {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
    }
}
```

y quiero poder sumarlos por ejemplo:

```js
new Vector2(1, 3) + new Vector2(5, 4) // Vector2(6, 7)
```

pero cuando lo hago me da

```js
"[object Object][object Object]"
```

como lo hago?

Comment: Creo que a lo que va tu pregunta es saber si hay una forma mas sencilla de hacer la suma no? Yo te recomendaría que si vas a hacer muchas veces esa suma, crees un método que te haga la suma mas fácil para ti, así solo tienes que crear el código 1 vez y la puedes usar todas las veces que necesites

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Debes proporcionar un [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacer esto. La más elegante es agregar un método a tu clase que se haga cargo de realizar la suma de las propiedades que sean de tipo numérico.

---

En JavaSCript no todos los objetos se pueden sumar, sólo los que se pueden convertir a números. Las sumas básicas se pueden realizar usando literales numéricos o variables que devuelvan un número ya sea de forma directa o porque los objetos referidos se han convertido a número.

Cabe destacar que un "problema" con JavaScript es que el operador `+` se usa tanto para sumar como para concatenar.

Como tu expresión de suma está usando como operandos **expresiones** que devuelven objetos, JavaScript intenta convertirlos a **primitivos** (número,  cadena de texto, entre otros) que pueda manejar. Dado que que la clase no incluye un método para hacer la conversión busca entre los prototipos el método a utilizar. En este caso el prototipo es `Object` y como no puede hacer la conversión a número, lo hace a una cadena de texto.

Relacionado

- [Todo en JavaScript es un objeto ¿cierto o falso?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/85853/65)
- [Conversion de tipos en javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/294763/65)

Recursos

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/class

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer de esta forma:

```js
class Vector2 {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
    }
}

let vector1=new Vector2(1,2);
let vector2=new Vector2(2,2);
let suma1=vector1.x+vector2.x;
let suma2=vector1.y+vector2.y;
let sumaTotal=new Vector2(suma1,suma2);
console.log(sumaTotal)
```

Comment: Hola Richard, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código sin una explicación clara de lo que hace no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios y se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor, edita esta respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle y una explicación de lo que hace el código y cómo soluciona el problema. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello también ganarás una nueva medalla).