# ¿Cómo puedo agregarles el signo de pesos mexicanos $ y separador de miles?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lo que quiero hacer es que en 1 input agregue el total, otro input ponga cuánto pago de anticipo y me dé resultado en otro input lo que se resta, pero con los signos de pesos y separador de miles $100.00

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    El producto cuesta: <input type="text" id="caja1" placeholder="Precio 1">
    <br><br>
    Estas pagando con: <input type="text" id="caja2" placeholder="Precio 2">
    <br><br>
    Tu cambio es : <input type="text" id="caja3" placeholder="Precio 3">
    <div id="aviso"></div>
    <script>
        let precio1 = document.getElementById("caja1")
        let precio2 = document.getElementById("caja2")
        let precio3 = document.getElementById("caja3")
        
        precio2.addEventListener("change", () => {
            precio3.value = parseFloat(precio2.value) - parseFloat(precio1.value)

        })
        
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Puedes mirar toLocaleString: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/294763/conversion-de-tipos-en-javascript/295051#295051

Comment: Otra opción es utlizar [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat), es bastante sencillo y te ofrece muchas otras opciones de personalización.

Comment: el signo $ me lo toma como un numero o carácter y no me deja restarlo me sale NAN, saben como podría  evitar eso?   XMASK = n.charAt(x-1) + XMASK, x--;
      } else if ( y && "$0".indexOf(mask.charAt(y-1))+1 ) {
        XMASK = mask.charAt(y-1) + XMASK;

Comment: Intenta colocar las preguntas adicionales, en la misma pregunta, leer código de los comentarios no es lo mas cómodo.

Answer (score 1):

podes usar este codigo para darle formato a tus numeros:

```js
var options = { style: 'currency', currency: 'MXN' }
var numberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-MX', options)
console.log(numberFormat.format(654321.987))
console.log(numberFormat.format(12))
console.log(numberFormat.format(1000000.259))
```

Podes ver este documento para mas información.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

```js
let precio1 = document.getElementById("caja1")
let precio2 = document.getElementById("caja2")
let precio3 = document.getElementById("caja3")
        
precio2.addEventListener("change", () => {
        
  var numberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-MX', { style: 'currency', currency: 'MXN' });
  precio3.value = numberFormat.format(parseFloat(precio2.value) - parseFloat(precio1.value))

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      El producto cuesta: <input type="text" id="caja1" placeholder="Precio 1">
      <br><br>
      Estas pagando con: <input type="text" id="caja2" placeholder="Precio 2">
      <br><br>
      Tu cambio es : <input type="text" id="caja3" placeholder="Precio 3">
      <div id="aviso"></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```